# Bike Paint White Dots - What Are they? Can they be fixed?

Tags: paint

I cleaned my bike and now I see these white dots on my paint.

Anyone know what they are? Can they be fixed,e.g. buffed out?

Thanks[image]

Comment: Chat did you clean with?

Comment: @mattnz -- What??

Comment: Probably buffed out, maybe a little polish.  Or just immerse the whole thing in what ever cleaner you've used, then at least you'll get a colour match

Comment: Are they water spots?  Where water has sat and damaged the paint?    Can you feel a surface difference with a finger ?

Comment: I used "STA-BIL SPORT Bike Wash - Bicycle Cleaning Spray" and most of the dots have disappeared. Kinda scary to see this after cleaning. Thanks all for the replies!